# How to get monthly and yearly visitor count with eloquent query

Tags: laravel

I have obtained the number of daily visitors using the following code.
How can I get the number of monthly and yearly visitors?

**Date Format : 2023-03-28**

```php
        $day = Visitor::where('time', '=', Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'));
        dd($day->count());
```

Answer (score 1):

Just combine two where clauses making a "between" comparison:

```
$day = Visitor::where('time', '>=', Carbon::now()->startOfMonth()->format('Y-m-d'))
->where('time', '<=', Carbon::now()->endOfMonth());

dd($day->count());
```

*Note:* To this query work properly, your `time` field must a date field, otherwise the comparison might not work properly.